# Not getting MIXED_DML_OPERATION error when updating setup & non-setup object in same transaction

Tags: apex, trigger, community

I am trying to update a **user & contact** object in the same transaction, just to do some analysis on that ***mixed_dml_operation*** error which we usually get in the case of DML on **setup & non-setup objects** in the same transaction.

I am wondering why I'm unable to see that error when trying to update records with the below code.

```
public void checkMixedDml(){
 Account account1 = [Select Id,name from Account limit 1];
 account1.name = 'test';
 update account1;
 User objUser = [Select Id from USER where Id =:UserInfo.getUserId()];
 objUser.lastname = 'TestLastName';
 update objUser;
}

checkMixedDml();
```

The above code is not throwing any error and working fine when executing from the Anonymous window. Any reason?

Thanks

Comment: Neither object is a setup object, to get the exception try adding a Queue record with the Account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the DML operations you are completing here, simply because of the field you are updating on the User object. A `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` exception will only be presented when certain fields (i.e relationships to setup objects) are populated on the `User` and certain class APIs are used. See [sObjects That Cannot Be Used Together in DML Operations](https://sfdctechie.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/sobjects-that-cannot-be-used-together-in-dml-operations/).

A quick test in your anon apex code would be to set the `UserRoleId` on the User object your are updating.

Note, this is commonly encountered in test methods as those setup objects are related to the User being tested i.e Queues, Permissions, Roles, Territories e.t.c